# How can i set the AnimatedContainer height to match it's child height content

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

we all know that `AnimatedContainer` widget working with two difference value size when it changed from size to other one

i have the following simple full code ,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late bool boolValue =  false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: AnimatedContainer(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: !boolValue? 200:0,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: const [
                Text('Hello world , Hello Dart',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15),),
                Text('Hello world , Hello Dart',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15),),
                Text('Hello world , Hello Dart',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15),),
                Text('Hello world , Hello Dart',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15),),
                Text('Hello world , Hello Dart',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 15),),
              ],
            ),
          ),
       )
      ),
        floatingActionButton:  FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor:  const Color(0xFFE57373),
            onPressed: (){
              setState(() {boolValue = !boolValue;});
            },
            child:  const Icon(Icons.check)
        )
    );
  }
}
```

ok now when i change my `boolValue` it animate from 200 as a height to 0 and vice versa
but the problem is that i want the height to be match to it's child height content it's self

in my previous example i used 200 as a height and it just for example , but if i did not put value  to height so the height will be great work as expected to it's child height but of course there will not be animation ..

Note: the Column item height depends on users inputs and it could be changed all the time , so i can't put fixed height value !

so How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually specify detailed `BoxConstraints` to suit your needs, rather than letting the container generate them for you.

Replacing the `height` argument with the following will animate the container between a forced minimum height of 200 and the height of its child.

`constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: !boolValue ? 200 : 0)`